# How to create a mask that fades out scrolled content, but does not overlap the scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

I have a container which *is not* the `body` element. This container is scrollable. Now the content should fade out at the top when scrolled.

This container itself is positioned `absolute`. The markup and CSS are not given and can be changed.

Unfortunately no matter what I try, I end up with two scenarios:

**1 The "mask" does scroll up as well:**

```css
.scrollable {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 40px 0;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.scrollable:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <p>
    Minions ipsum aaaaaah tank yuuu! Tank yuuu! Gelatooo poopayee. Baboiii po kass tank yuuu!
    Uuuhhh aaaaaah belloo!  Jeje bananaaaa daa wiiiii tulaliloo. Baboiii hahaha pepete la
    bodaaa belloo! Bappleees uuuhhh bananaaaa tank yuuu! La bodaaa. Tatata bala tu tank
    yuuu! Hahaha pepete wiiiii underweaaar baboiii bappleees. Tank yuuu! daa aaaaaah
    belloo! Tatata bala tu poulet tikka masala uuuhhh potatoooo pepete hana dul sae.
    Minions ipsum aaaaaah tank yuuu! Tank yuuu! Gelatooo poopayee. Baboiii po kass tank yuuu!
    Uuuhhh aaaaaah belloo!  Jeje bananaaaa daa wiiiii tulaliloo. Baboiii hahaha pepete la
    bodaaa belloo! Bappleees uuuhhh bananaaaa tank yuuu! La bodaaa. Tatata bala tu tank
    yuuu! Hahaha pepete wiiiii underweaaar baboiii bappleees. Tank yuuu! daa aaaaaah
    belloo! Tatata bala tu poulet tikka masala uuuhhh potatoooo pepete hana dul sae.
  </p>
</div>
```

**2 The "mask" is overlapping the scrollbar:**

```css
 .scrollable {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.scrollable:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 40px 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <p class="content">
    Minions ipsum aaaaaah tank yuuu! Tank yuuu! Gelatooo poopayee. Baboiii po kass tank yuuu!
    Uuuhhh aaaaaah belloo!  Jeje bananaaaa daa wiiiii tulaliloo. Baboiii hahaha pepete la
    bodaaa belloo! Bappleees uuuhhh bananaaaa tank yuuu! La bodaaa. Tatata bala tu tank
    yuuu! Hahaha pepete wiiiii underweaaar baboiii bappleees. Tank yuuu! daa aaaaaah
    belloo! Tatata bala tu poulet tikka masala uuuhhh potatoooo pepete hana dul sae.
    Minions ipsum aaaaaah tank yuuu! Tank yuuu! Gelatooo poopayee. Baboiii po kass tank yuuu!
    Uuuhhh aaaaaah belloo!  Jeje bananaaaa daa wiiiii tulaliloo. Baboiii hahaha pepete la
    bodaaa belloo! Bappleees uuuhhh bananaaaa tank yuuu! La bodaaa. Tatata bala tu tank
    yuuu! Hahaha pepete wiiiii underweaaar baboiii bappleees. Tank yuuu! daa aaaaaah
    belloo! Tatata bala tu poulet tikka masala uuuhhh potatoooo pepete hana dul sae.
  </p>
</div>
```

I also tried adding another container to act as the "mask" with different z-indexes, tried fixed positioning etc.

So, I can't figure out any other markup and CSS where:

- the content is scrollable
- the "mask" stays at the top
- the "mask" doesn't overlap the scrollbar

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try position sticky. If you use this make sure you're ok with the current browser support. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

```css
.scrollable {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.scrollable:before {
  content: '';
  position: sticky;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <p>
    Minions ipsum aaaaaah tank yuuu! Tank yuuu! Gelatooo poopayee. Baboiii po kass tank yuuu! Uuuhhh aaaaaah belloo! Jeje bananaaaa daa wiiiii tulaliloo. Baboiii hahaha pepete la bodaaa belloo! Bappleees uuuhhh bananaaaa tank yuuu! La bodaaa. Tatata bala
    tu tank yuuu! Hahaha pepete wiiiii underweaaar baboiii bappleees. Tank yuuu! daa aaaaaah belloo! Tatata bala tu poulet tikka masala uuuhhh potatoooo pepete hana dul sae. Minions ipsum aaaaaah tank yuuu! Tank yuuu! Gelatooo poopayee. Baboiii po kass
    tank yuuu! Uuuhhh aaaaaah belloo! Jeje bananaaaa daa wiiiii tulaliloo. Baboiii hahaha pepete la bodaaa belloo! Bappleees uuuhhh bananaaaa tank yuuu! La bodaaa. Tatata bala tu tank yuuu! Hahaha pepete wiiiii underweaaar baboiii bappleees. Tank yuuu!
    daa aaaaaah belloo! Tatata bala tu poulet tikka masala uuuhhh potatoooo pepete hana dul sae.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `calc()` to substract the width of the scrollbar from the overlay:

```css
 .scrollable {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.scrollable:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 18px);
  height: 60px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 40px 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <p class="content">
    Minions ipsum aaaaaah tank yuuu! Tank yuuu! Gelatooo poopayee. Baboiii po kass tank yuuu!
    Uuuhhh aaaaaah belloo!  Jeje bananaaaa daa wiiiii tulaliloo. Baboiii hahaha pepete la
    bodaaa belloo! Bappleees uuuhhh bananaaaa tank yuuu! La bodaaa. Tatata bala tu tank
    yuuu! Hahaha pepete wiiiii underweaaar baboiii bappleees. Tank yuuu! daa aaaaaah
    belloo! Tatata bala tu poulet tikka masala uuuhhh potatoooo pepete hana dul sae.
    Minions ipsum aaaaaah tank yuuu! Tank yuuu! Gelatooo poopayee. Baboiii po kass tank yuuu!
    Uuuhhh aaaaaah belloo!  Jeje bananaaaa daa wiiiii tulaliloo. Baboiii hahaha pepete la
    bodaaa belloo! Bappleees uuuhhh bananaaaa tank yuuu! La bodaaa. Tatata bala tu tank
    yuuu! Hahaha pepete wiiiii underweaaar baboiii bappleees. Tank yuuu! daa aaaaaah
    belloo! Tatata bala tu poulet tikka masala uuuhhh potatoooo pepete hana dul sae.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought about that too, but is the width of the scrollbar consistent across all browsers?

Comment: I don't think that's the case, but firefox allows you to control width of the scrollbar, more here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `radial-gradient` instead. That way the corners won't overlap the scroll and the effect looks very nice.

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.scrollable {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  max-height:100%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
section:before {
  content:"";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
  background-position: center -10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="scrollable">
    <p>
      Minions ipsum aaaaaah tank yuuu! Tank yuuu! Gelatooo poopayee. Baboiii po kass tank yuuu!
      Uuuhhh aaaaaah belloo!</p><p>Jeje bananaaaa daa wiiiii tulaliloo. Baboiii hahaha pepete la
      bodaaa belloo! Bappleees uuuhhh bananaaaa tank yuuu! La bodaaa. Tatata bala tu tank
      yuuu! Hahaha pepete wiiiii underweaaar baboiii bappleees. Tank yuuu! daa aaaaaah</p><p>
      belloo! Tatata bala tu poulet tikka masala uuuhhh potatoooo pepete hana dul sae.
      Minions ipsum aaaaaah tank yuuu! Tank yuuu! Gelatooo poopayee. Baboiii po kass tank yuuu!
      Uuuhhh aaaaaah belloo!</p><p>Jeje bananaaaa daa wiiiii tulaliloo. Baboiii hahaha pepete la
      bodaaa belloo! Bappleees uuuhhh bananaaaa tank yuuu! La bodaaa. Tatata bala tu tank
      yuuu! Hahaha pepete wiiiii underweaaar baboiii bappleees. Tank yuuu! daa aaaaaah
      belloo! Tatata bala tu poulet tikka masala uuuhhh potatoooo pepete hana dul sae.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

However, if you prefer to use the `linear-gradient`, you can use $(selector).prop('clientWidth') to get the content available width and apply it to the shade. Remember that that element **can't be** a *:pseudoelement*

```js
$('.shade').css('width', function(){
var scrollableWidth = $('.content').prop('clientWidth');
return scrollableWidth;
});
```

```css
.scrollable {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.shade {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="shade"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Minions ipsum aaaaaah tank yuuu! Tank yuuu! Gelatooo poopayee. Baboiii po kass tank yuuu!</p><p>
    Uuuhhh aaaaaah belloo!  Jeje bananaaaa daa wiiiii tulaliloo. Baboiii hahaha pepete la
    bodaaa belloo! Bappleees uuuhhh bananaaaa tank yuuu! La bodaaa. Tatata bala tu tank
    yuuu! Hahaha pepete wiiiii underweaaar baboiii bappleees. Tank yuuu! daa aaaaaah
    belloo! Tatata bala tu poulet tikka masala uuuhhh potatoooo pepete hana dul sae.
    Minions ipsum aaaaaah tank yuuu! Tank yuuu! Gelatooo poopayee. Baboiii po kass tank yuuu!
    Uuuhhh aaaaaah belloo!  Jeje bananaaaa daa wiiiii tulaliloo. Baboiii hahaha pepete la
    bodaaa belloo! Bappleees uuuhhh bananaaaa tank yuuu! La bodaaa. Tatata bala tu tank
    yuuu! Hahaha pepete wiiiii underweaaar baboiii bappleees. Tank yuuu! daa aaaaaah
    belloo! Tatata bala tu poulet tikka masala uuuhhh potatoooo pepete hana dul sae.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```